# Laravel 5 Login Function change argument

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I override the function login in LoginController.
by default she was in the Trait: Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

This function in LoginController in Laravel must take param 
of type \Illuminate\Http\Request.

if i change this param on my custom request 
error when submitting form 403|Forbidden

Request created with composer:

> php artisan make:request StoreBlogPost

Can I do something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the `authorize` method in your custom request returns `true` by default instead of false so you are able to make the request.